# Possible instance of reported upvote going to wrong question

Tags: support, comments, voting

This could just be a coincidence or a misinterpretation, but I'm reporting it in case it's actually a bug. (EDIT: not a bug - just an errant comment. See the comments at the second linked SO question.)

I don't get a lot of upvotes on old questions, but just today I got a report in [the "reputation" part of my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58845/jtolle?tab=reputation) that someone upvoted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806229/what-is-a-function-that-takes-no-arguments-called), even though I have a comment at the same time by a user who says they upvoted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541342/when-called-from-an-excel-vba-udf-range-precedents-returns-the-range-and-not-it).

Unfortunately I can't remember how many votes either question had before. Of course, it could either be a coincidence, or the comment could be inaccurate. This is obviously not urgent but I wanted to provide the report in case it's something real but rare.

Comment: -3: don't believe those numbers people put in front of comments. You can type *anything* in there...

Comment: -1 but I didn't downvote!

Comment: @Shog9: Yeah, me neither, but there *is* a simultaneous upvote on a different question. Maybe the same user upvoted the other question, but the comment is clearly related to the question that is *not* reported as getting an upvote. Just trying to be helpful! But downvote away if this is inappropriate in some way.

Comment: @jtolle: it's totally appropriate - there's just not much that can be done about it right now, other than make jokes in comments ;-). But it'll be here, waiting, if anyone else ever sees the same thing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm gonna go with the simplest explanation here: the user voted on one question, and then left a comment on the other.

Why? Who knows... Bizarre mistake involving your profile page (they're your two newest questions), desire to give you rep after having already voted on the commented question previously, or perhaps even just a juvenile desire to cause some confusion.

Failing that, let's blame "solar winds".

Comment: I asked brettdj via a comment response, so perhaps he or she will see this meta thread and comment. I doubt it's a real bug, but you never know if someone is hunting something and just needs one...more...datum...

Comment: The most likely explanation from the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5541342/timeline) is that the user commented on the question but actually upvoted the accepted answer.

Comment: Quite possible, @Rick... though whether that is the case, and if so, if it was intentional or unintentional, is impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Interesting note about the timeline. I didn't know you could see stuff like that. Thanks.

Comment: Today's excuse is [Serious Request Infection](http://bofhcalendar.com/).

Comment: brettdj did comment on the SO question, and it was just an erroneous comment. Thanks for actually looking into it.

Comment: I thought there was the habit to blame the cosmic rays. When did we start blaming the solar winds? I don't want the solar winds enter in my computer!